# how to pass from form to database and add relation in one swoop

Tags: php, laravel

As the title say I have model relationship has many. I'm sending data trough form

first model has

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

second has

```
public function comment()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Comments');
}
```

controller is this

```
$post->request->all();
$post->save();

$comment = new Comments;
$comment->pst = $request->pst;

$post->comment()->save($comment);
```

And it's not saving. Don't know where I am making a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$post->request->all();
$post = $post->save();

$comment = new Comments;
$comment->pst = $request->pst;

$post->comment()->save($comment);
```